# Web Page Icon's Changing Problem in Multiple Page App

Tags: python, streamlit

Version: Streamlit 1.13.0

Structure:
Main folder > 1__main.py

in pages folder > 2_❌_project.py

In 1__main.py:

```
st.set_page_config(
page_title= “Multipage App”,
page_icon=)
```

When I press ❌ in the sidebar,  icon is disappearing in the header tab. Streamlit theme comes instead.
How Can I solve this problem? Which icon do I press in the sidebar, the header icon must seem same. I want to make this.

**Example scenario:**

**In the beginning like this:**

[image]

**Then, I click on Application:**
[image]

**Folder icon disappears, streamlit icon comes (Unwanted situation):**

[image]

Comment: Your question is not pretty clear. Can you explain clearly with more details?

Answer (score 1):

In every page file, every piece of code including the `page_config` should be in a function, you can name that the `main function` and pass every code into it:
for e.g:

```py
# Homepage

import streamlit as st
...

def main()
    st.set_page_config("Replace me with your page config")
    # The rest of your code
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:** Apply same rule to the rest of your page files.

Comment: This is how it should be done, but in case you try and still it doesn't work, you can paste one of your pages file content if you don't mind, or at least a demo code, so I or someone else can help fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution did not work.

Comment: All the files that are pages should have this same format otherwise you will always get same error because of the `st.set_page_config`. That is the only way to get it working when you intend to use  `st.set_page_config`. If you observe, without `st.set_page_config` you will not run into such error.